# Pandas Crosstabulation and counting

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python Pandas. I have got a column with a string and I would like to have the crossing between the columns.

E.g I have got the following input

```
1: Andi
2: Andi, Cindy
3: Thomas, Cindy
4: Cindy, Thomas
```

And I would like to have the following output:

Hence, the combination of Andi and Thomas does not appear in the data, but Cindy and Thomas appear twice.

```
          Andi  Thomas  Cindy
    Andi    1     0      1
    Thomas  0     1      2
    Cindy   1     2      1
```

Has somebody any idea how I could handle this? That would be really great!

Many thanks and regards,

Andi

Answer (score 9):

You can generate the dummy columns first:

```
df['A'].str.get_dummies(', ')
Out: 
   Andi  Cindy  Thomas
0     1      0       0
1     1      1       0
2     0      1       1
3     0      1       1
```

And use that in the dot product:

```
tab = df['A'].str.get_dummies(', ')

tab.T.dot(tab)
Out: 
        Andi  Cindy  Thomas
Andi       2      1       0
Cindy      1      3       2
Thomas     0      2       2
```

Diagonal entries will give you the number of occurrences for each person. If you need to set the diagonals to 1, there are [several alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475094/set-values-on-the-diagonal-of-pandas-dataframe). One of them is [`np.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) from numpy.

```
co_occurrence = tab.T.dot(tab)    
np.fill_diagonal(co_occurrence.values, 1)    
co_occurrence
Out: 
        Andi  Cindy  Thomas
Andi       1      1       0
Cindy      1      1       2
Thomas     0      2       1
```

Comment: great answer! (-;

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you. :)

Comment: @ayhan This is the reason why I like Stack Overflow.  I learn a great use of `.dot` to calculate crosstab reports from series.  +1

Comment: @piRSquared perfect and great answer ;)